# Expense ratio of an ETF included in the price or calculated separately

Tags: etf, expense-ratio

If an expense ratio of an ETF is 0.15% and the ETF is trading at 100, then when I buy the ETF, do I pay 100? Or do I pay 100.0015?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expense ratio reduces the *return* of the ETF; your scenario of paying 100.0015 is that of a *load.*  Most (all?)
ETFs can be bought without paying a load (sales charge as a percent of amount invested), and some ETFs can be bought without paying a brokerage fee (fixed
or variable charge for a buy transaction just like buying any other stock 
through the brokerage) because the brokerage has waived it.  *Your* broker 
might charge
fees for both buying and selling shares in an ETF, but in any case, this is
quite separate from the expense ratio.